# Detecting conflicts between parent repo and fork without actually pulling

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I'd like to solve the following problem:
I have a repository (call it A) and a clone of it (call it B). I made some changes in B and I want to ask the owner of A to pull it. I'd like to implement a function that can figure out if the changes in B can be pulled to A without causing any conflicts. I want to implement this in such a way that doesn't corrupt the information in A (so anyone who clones A sees exactly the same than before this confict detection).

Please note that I'd like to solve it the more efficient way. I saw that bitbucket performs this check for pull requests very fast. Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a *pull* won't create any conflicts by itself. It just adds changesets to a repository history, possibly also adding new branches/heads. You might get conflicts when merging such heads. So when *A* pulls from *B*, there is nothing broken in *A*.

However, if you want the owner of *A* to include your changes, what you actually have to do is to pull recent changes from *A* into your *B* and - if needed - merge the new changes from *A* into your new changes. Then request a pull from your now merged *B*, which *A* can pull without adding new heads and thus without possibly having to deal with conflicts.

If you don't want to follow that common workflow but really want to check it as described in your question, just create a new clone of *A*, let's say *C*, and try to pull and merge from *B* into *C*. But finally you'll end up in the steps mentioned above anyway.

Comment: If the merge causes conflicts, you can undo it with "hg update -C -r ."

Comment: Thanks, I will advise this if there are conflicts. But before I have to detect if there are conflicts or not. My probblem with pulling is that after you pulled some changesets to a repo those changesets will be visible in the repo's clone, too.

Comment: @akostajti, I don't really understand the pull problem: you do not want to pull from A into B because now clones of B see the pulled changesets?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create another clone of A and do the merge there? This way you know how the merge went, and you don't mess up A.

Comment: I have huge repositories so cloning temporarily is a huge overhead.